# How to change the font color first line of a list...up to the <br>

Tags: css, list, css-selectors

Is there a simple way to change the font color of the first line of a list, but only if it ends with a [break].

For example:

```
<ul>
<li>THIS WOULD BE IN ORANGE REGARDLESS OF WHERE IT BREAKS EVEN IF IT RUNS TO TWO LINES [break]<br> 
Then the rest of the paragraph etc. etc. in the usual text color.</li>
</ul>

<ul>
<li>This would be in the usual text color. Just your typical text, no headline.</li>
</ul>
```

Tried all kinds of `::before`, `::first-line` type pseudo selectors.

Probably can't be done; essentially trying to select everything between `ul` `li` and the first `br`!

Comment: This is not possible with pure CSS AFAIK. You'd have to wrap the first "line" in a span and then apply the color rule or go for a JavaScript solution.

Comment: This could work if you add `white-space:nowrap` to `li` however, it will make all content in one line and breaks only occur with `br` tags... see jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/azizn/5mtw7426/1/

Comment: Guess I'm asking how to use CSS to format the first SENTENCE, rather than the first line.  Maybe one day...

Answer (score 1):

You cannot achieve it by simple CSS.

BUT, you can achieve it simply via JQUERY.

See this FIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/bgo7osrj/

HTML:

```
<button class="btn">Test</button>
<ul id="ulId">
<li>THIS WOULD BE IN ORANGE REGARDLESS OF WHERE IT BREAKS EVEN IF IT RUNS TO TWO LINES [break]<br> 
Then the rest of the paragraph etc. etc. in the usual text color.</li>
</ul>

<ul>
<li>This would be in the usual text color. Just your typical text, no headline.</li>
</ul>
```

Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".btn").click(function(){
var text = $("#ulId").children().first().html().replace('<br>', '</span><br>');
text = "<span style='color:orange;'>" + text;
$("#ulId").children().first().html(text);
});
});
 /*replace used without regex, should be replaced only first <br> found,
  then you can have as many other <br> as you wish*/
```